# Using custom class view in django get me error

Tags: python, django, class, view

I'm learning django and i'm trying to create my own custom class in a views.py file

This class i would use have to method, one for classical HTML rendering, and another for json response

my class in views.py

```py
class myListView():
    context = {}
    def __init__(self, request):
        request = request
        context['PageTitle'] = 'Contacts'
        context['people'] = People.objects.all()

    def htmlRender(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context['children_template'] = 'people/list.html'
        return render(request,'base.html',context)

    def jsonRender(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(self.context['people']), content_type="application/json")
```

my urls.py

```py
    path('list', login_required(myListView.htmlRender()), name='list'),
    path('list/json', login_required(myListView.jsonRender()), name='list'),
```

Here is the error sended by debugger :

```
TypeError: htmlRender() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I don't have any idea how to solve this, maybe i'm dreaming about using custom class in view ?

Thanks'you

Comment: What about myListView().htmlRender() ?

Comment: If i write this in urls, that is the reponse    TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class myListView(ListView):
```

Maybe you are not extending the ListView Class, try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You should first create an instance from "myListView" class then use it :

```
myListViewInstance = myListView(arguments)

myListViewInstance.htmlRender()
```